# React native run useState/force rerender inside worklet funtion

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm calling the `useAnimatedScrollHandler` hook from [react-native-reanimated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated) to handle my `onScroll` function on an `Animated.ScrollView`. This hook works as expected but I now want to disable a custom button (My FlatButton) based on the `currentIndex` which is a `sharedValue`. But when the sharedValue changes the screen doesn't get rerendered, because the state doesn't change so the look of my button remains the same.
Is there a way to force a rerender inside of a worklet, or is it possible to use `useState` to force a rerender from inside a worklet?

```js
const scrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler((event) => {
  translationX.value = event.contentOffset.x
  if (event.contentOffset.x < width * 0.5 && currentIndex.value != 0) {
    currentIndex.value = 0
  } else if (
    event.contentOffset.x > width * 0.5 &&
    event.contentOffset.x < width * 1.5 &&
    currentIndex.value != 1
  ) {
    currentIndex.value = 1
  } else if (event.contentOffset.x > width * 1.5 && currentIndex.value != 2) {
    currentIndex.value = 2
  }
})
```

```js
<FlatButton
  label="Next"
  disabled={
    (currentIndex.value == 0 && (!firstName || !lastName)) ||
    (currentIndex.value == 1 && (!dateOfBirth || !sex)) ||
    (currentIndex.value == 2 &&
      (!streetNumber || !postalCode || !city || !state || !country))
  }
  onPress={() => {
    if (currentIndex.value == 0) {
      scrollRef.current
        ?.getNode()
        .scrollTo({ x: width, animated: true })
    } else if (currentIndex.value == 1) {
      scrollRef.current?.getNode().scrollToEnd({ animated: true })
    }
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found out that reanimated offers the function [runOnJS](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/runOnJS/) which makes it possible to run a javscript function like `setState` inside a worklet. So just create a wrapper function, like in my case `toggleIndex` in which you interact with your state and call this function inside `runOnJS` from your worklet.

```js
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)

const toggleIndex = (index: number) => {
  setCurrentIndex(index)
}

const scrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler((event) => {
  translationX.value = event.contentOffset.x
  if (event.contentOffset.x < width * 0.5 && currentIndex != 0) {
    runOnJS(toggleIndex)(0)
  } else if (
    event.contentOffset.x > width * 0.5 &&
    event.contentOffset.x < width * 1.5 &&
    currentIndex != 1
  ) {
    runOnJS(toggleIndex)(1)
  } else if (event.contentOffset.x > width * 1.5 && currentIndex != 2) {
    runOnJS(toggleIndex)(2)
  }
})
```

Comment: Cheers, helped me figure out how to use useState, useEffect, and runOnJs! Saved me loads of time.