# How to call useState setter inside a worklet function?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, react-native, react-native-reanimated, worklet

I'm trying to call the React useState setter function from within a worklet function. This callback is provided by the package - https://github.com/mgcrea/react-native-dnd which exposes an onDragEnd event.

I've found [other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68801012/1829251) suggesting to use runOnJS from react-native-reanimated in order to run JS code from within the UI thread (this worklet function). But console logs within `runOnJS` and in the render function itself is not updated when the `handleDragEnd` is emit.

What needs to change in order to call the useState setter within a worklet function?

Below is a snippet showing the worklet and some of the render function:

```js
import {runOnJS} from 'react-native-reanimated';

  const handleDragEnd: DndProviderProps['onDragEnd'] = ({active, over}) => {
    'worklet';
    if (over) {
      console.log('onDragEnd', {active, over});
      console.log(active);

      // Create a new item based on the type of the dragged item
      const newItem = {
        partName: `${active.id.split('-')[0]}`,
      };

      runOnJS(() => {
        // Add the new item to ductItems
        setDuctItems((prevDuctItems) => {
          const updatedDuctItems = [...prevDuctItems, newItem];
          console.log('Updated ductItems:', updatedDuctItems);
          return updatedDuctItems;
        });
      });

      dynamicData.value = {
        over: over,
      };
    }
  };

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <DndProvider
          onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}
          >
          <Droppable id="drop" style={styles.dropBox}>
            <Text>DROP</Text>
          </Droppable>
          <View style={styles.partsContainer}>
            <Text>{JSON.stringify(ductItems)}</Text>
            {ductItems.map((item, index) => (
              <DraggableCustomComponent
                style={styles.partItem}
                id={`${item.partName}-${index}-key`}
                key={`${item.partName}-${index}-key`}
                partType={item.partName}
                data={dynamicData}
              />
            ))}
          </View>
        </DndProvider>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I wasn't invoking runOnJs correctly [according to the reanimated docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/threading/runOnJS/). The function uses "currying" pattern which takes the args as last param:

```js
const replaceDuctPart = (item: {partName: string}) => {
    setDuctItems((prevDuctItems) => {
      const updatedDuctItems = [...prevDuctItems, item];
      console.log('Updated ductItems:', updatedDuctItems);
      return updatedDuctItems;
    });
  };

runOnJS(replaceDuctPart)(newItem);
```